# concavity of a vector function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm given a function $g:\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$,  $g(y) = \prod_{i\in[n]} (1+y_i\cdot c_i)$, where $c_i>0$.
Let $e_a,e_b$ be two arbitrary standard vectors. It is easy to show that for any $y,a,b$ the function $z \mapsto g(y + z(e_a - e_b))$ is concave.

My problem is the following. I need to consider, for a fixed $y$, a function of all possible swaps between standard vectors, i.e., $h\left( (z_{ab})_{a,b\in[n]} \right) = g(y + \sum_{a,b} z_{ab}(e_a-e_b))$. For such a function I would like to use Jensen's inequality, and so I need to argue that the function $h\left( (z_{ab})_{a,b\in[n]} \right)$ is concave.
Can I argue as follows?

1. For any $(z_{ab})_{a,b\in[n]}$:
2. the function is strictly concave in every standard direction, i.e., $z_{ab}$, hence
3. since the function is $C^\infty$
4. in appropriately small neighborhood of $(z_{ab})_{a,b\in[n]}$ the function is concave, therefore
5. the function is concave everywhere.

Comment: First of all, how is it from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $[0,1]$?

Comment: You mean $g$? It takes $n$ numbers and outputs a product of $n$ numbers. Function $h$ is from $\mathbb{R}^{n(n-1)/2}$.

Comment: Yes, $g$, why do its values belong to $[0,1]$?

Comment: Sorry, a mistake. It's from $\mathbb{R}$. The original I was considering was from $[0,1]$ because it had a normalization factor.

Comment: Basically, I wanted to know if this is a well established fact. I think I can come up with a tailored argument using the fact that the function is quite simple, but would prefer to rely on a general property.

Comment: The function $f(x,y)=3xy-x^2-y^2$ is strictly concave at the point $(0,0)$ in every standard direction (either $x=0$ or $y=0$) but is not concave in direction $x=y$.